# Advanced Custom Fields/User Role Editor - how to hide ACF for certain users?

Tags: plugins, user-roles, permissions, advanced-custom-fields

I am using User Role Editor to specify customized user roles. I am also using Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

I would like to be able to hide Advanced Custom Fields from showing up for certain users; however, the only way to do this in User Role Editor is to uncheck "Manage Options" box. The problem with doing this is it removes other plugins from showing up which I in fact would like to show up for those users.

Is there a bit of manual code I can place in my functions.php that will remove only Advanced Custom Fields for certain user roles? Just this plugin.

Answer (score 4):

The `admin_menu` action will hide the ACF menu, in this example for not-admins.

And `admin_head` will block the access if the URL is accessed directly.
E.g.: `http://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=acf` and `http://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=acf&page=acf-settings`

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse_59032_remove_acf_menu', 9999 );
add_action( 'admin_head-edit.php', 'wpse_59032_block_acf_screens' );
add_action( 'admin_head-custom-fields_page_acf-settings', 'wpse_59032_block_acf_screens' );

function wpse_59032_remove_acf_menu() 
{
    /* if not our allowed users, hide menu */
    if ( !current_user_can('delete_plugins') ) {
        remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=acf');
    }
}

function wpse_59032_block_acf_screens()
{   
    global $current_screen;

    /* not our screen, do nothing */
    if( 'edit-acf' != $current_screen->id && 'custom-fields_page_acf-settings' != $current_screen->id )
        return;

    /* if not our allowed users, block access */
    if ( !current_user_can('delete_plugins') ) {
        wp_die('message');
    }

}
```