# Remove Advanced Custom Fields plugin for client?

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I just have a quick question... I am using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin on a site for a costumer, just to get a little more power into it.... but I wouldn't want the client to be poking around in there, and get all confused... is there an easy none-obtrusive way to sort of hide the options from the end user, bdut still keep the functionality around? I'm guessing a more generic google search would probably help me out, but it would be great to just get some feedback from u guys :)

-cheers
kriwis

Comment: Welcome to WPSE :) First: This site is no replacement for a google search. Second, [there're support routes for this plugin](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59032/advanced-custom-fields-user-role-editor-how-to-hide-acf-for-certain-users) looks like a very similar question. Take a look at @brasofilo's [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/59048/13810), you can modify for your own needs.

There are a couple of ways you could approach this: you could set up a [custom role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) for your client's user accounts, giving them all the rights of an admin. [Add a capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap) to the main admin role (`$role = get_role("admin"); $role->add_cap("edit_acf_fields",)`), then using these hooks to check for that role and deny access.

```
$current_user = get_current_user();

// If the user doesn't have the capability, no editing ACF settings.
if ( !$current_user->has_cap("edit_acf_fields") {
    // hide the menus
    // or kill the screens
}
```

The main reason to do this is portability. You (or the client) might want someone else to work on their site one day, they'll need their own account. More complex, but the recommended solution.

Alternatively, you can just check for your own email address and call it a day:

```
$current_user = get_current_user();

if ( $current_user->user_email == "yourEmail@example.com" ) {
    // hide the menus
    // or kill the screens
}
```

This is essentially invoking magic numbers, as an editing screen appears or disappears based on who you are, and there's no obvious explanation or way to change that behavior to the user. Easy, but Not Recommended.

Comment: thanks for the responses Much appreciated! I realize that i could have done a better job googling. To be honest this problem was yanking my chain to a insane degree, so I basically jumped the gun to ask, after not finding what i was looking for for a while.. thanks again for being so helpful, despite the fact that I kind of disregarded etiquette on this one. Won't happen again ;) (all too often)

Answer (score 1):

Yes! There's the [Advanced Custom Fields Lite](https://github.com/elliotcondon/acf-lite/) plugin that gives you all options without any Menu.

You just need to export fields that you created using the normal [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin.